Has any spacecraft ever been severely damaged by a micrometeorite?
Has any spacecraft ever been severely damaged by a micrometeorite? By severely damaged, I mean it either ended or significantly impacted the mission. Has this ever happened?

Does space debris count or does it have to be a natural object?

I'm honestly interested in both@OrganicMarble

Interest only" The Telstar1  satellite was degraded to unusability by radiation from the Starfish Prime nuclear test. See eg https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/how-us-accidentally-nuked-own-communications-satellite/

Many times. It happens more than you think.

The Space Shuttle did take damage from micrometeoroids and orbital debris (MMOD).  There's a bunch of photos here:  https://hvit.jsc.nasa.gov/impact-images/space-shuttle.cfm

@Adam that's a really nice collection! Here's a window impact; hat-tip to Tim Peake

There's also this bit they brought back from a Hubble servicing mission you can see at the Smithsonian air & space museum, though note that the holes are actually just parts they cut out to analyze and not the direct damage https://airandspace.si.edu/multimedia-gallery/6572hjpg


Has any spacecraft ever been severely damaged by a micrometeorite? By severely damaged, I mean it either ended or significantly impacted the mission? Has this ever happened?

Yes:
Soyuz MS-22 in 2023

Damaged Russian Soyuz capsule lands back on Earth from space station
March 28 (Reuters) - A damaged Russian Soyuz MS-22 capsule landed back on Earth on Tuesday, three months after coolant began leaking from the craft while it was docked at the International Space Station (ISS).
The module completed the almost two-hour return from the ISS without a crew, landing in the Kazakh steppe on Tuesday afternoon, a few hundred kilometres from the Baikonur cosmodrome, home to Russia's space launches.
The landing was broadcast online by the Russian space agency Roscosmos.
A significant coolant leak was discovered in the capsule last December - caused by a 0.8-millimetre hole in its outer skin.
A tiny meteorite is likely to have pierced the structure while it was docked, experts say. Images captured from the exterior of the ISS showed coolant fluid spewing into space, while Roscosmos said temperatures at one point rose to 30 Celsius (86 Fahrenheit) inside the capsule.


https://www.reuters.com/lifestyle/science/damaged-russian-soyuz-capsule-lands-back-earth-2023-03-28/
Also:

Gaia spacecraft almost doomed by back-to-back meteor strike, 2024
https://www.livescience.com/space/space-exploration/gaia-spacecraft-almost-doomed-by-back-to-back-meteor-strike-and-solar-storm-but-esa-says-theyve-found-a-solution
the European Space Agency's Gaia spacecraft was recently slammed by a micrometeoroid and struck by a solar storm, leaving it unable to function properly.
Gaia orbits at more than 932,000 miles (1.5 million kilometers) from Earth at what is known as the L2 Lagrange Point, where the combined gravitational forces of our planet and the sun create a stable orbit. The spacecraft's goal is to create a 3D map of the individual stars in the Milky Way.
But in April, a meteoroid smaller than a grain of sand hit Gaia and damaged the protective shield surrounding its instrumentation. In the months since, sunlight sneaking through this tiny crack has disrupted the spacecraft's sensors, according to ESA.



Olympus-1 was a communications satellite that suffered the loss of an on-board gyro during the height of the Perseid meteor shower, in August 1993. The satellite spun out of control and efforts to stabilise it resulted in the expenditure of the majority of its fuel.
https://spectrum.ieee.org/shooting-stars-can-shoot-down-satellites
https://web.archive.org/web/20110928011943/http://www.selkirkshire.demon.co.uk/analoguesat/olympus.html


non-natural impact:
Iridium 33 was a communications satellite that on 10th February 2009, collided with a derelict Strela satellite (Kosmos 2251). Both were destroyed.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2009_satellite_collision



https://web.archive.org/web/20100527132915/http://orbitaldebris.jsc.nasa.gov/newsletter/pdfs/ODQNv13i2.pdf
Non-meteoroid related collision:

1997 Progress M-34 collided with the Mir space station during a docking test whilst under manual control using the then-new TORU system. The Progress spacecraft collided with the space stations Spektr module, damaging both the module itself, and a solar panel. Spektr was left depressurized and isolated from the rest of the Mir space station complex.

DART (Demonstration for Autonomous Rendezvous Technology) was launched in 2005 but ended its mission early after a low-velocity collision with its intended docking target, the MUBLCOM (Multiple-Path Beyond-Line-of-Sight Communications) satellite. (By the way, this is not the DART that deliberately hit an asteroid).

May 2013, the Ecuadorean satellite NEE-01 Pegaso, suffered a glancing blow from debris of a 1985 Tsyklon-3 rocket. Spinning out of control it was considered a total loss.

March 2021, Chinese satellite Yunhai-1 (02) broke up after a collision with debris from a 1996 Zenit-2 launch vehicle for Cosmos 2333.


Other types of collisions:

2007 Chinese anti-satellite missile test - Polar orbit satellite FY-1C was destroyed by the SC-19 (a modified DF-21 ballistic missile with a Kinetic Kill Vehicle) in an ASAT test.

As a result of the 2007 Chinese ASAT test, debris from that test collided with the Russian satellite BLITS in early 2013, prematurely ending that satellites mission.

In 1985, US satellite P78-1 (Solwind) was destroyed in an ASM-135 ASAT anti-satellite missile test.

February 2008 the cruiser USS Lake Erie, using a heavily modified SM-3 missile shot down the satellite USA-193.

2019 India conducted an ASAT test, using the Prithvi Defence Vehicle Mark-II to destroy a suspected Microsat-R satellite.


https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Burnt_Frost
https://www.thisdayinaviation.com/tag/solwind-p78-1/
https://www.nationalmuseum.af.mil/Visit/Museum-Exhibits/Fact-Sheets/Display/Article/198034/vought-asm-135a-anti-satellite-missile/
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satellite_collision
https://www.russianspaceweb.com/mir_spektr.html
https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/av/magazine-36549109
https://www.nasa.gov/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/148072main_dart_mishap_overview.pdf?emrc=222d09
https://spacenews.com/breakup-of-chinas-yunhai-1-02-satellite-linked-to-space-debris-collision/
Note:

In 1996 the French satellite Cerise collided with debris from the Ariane 1 rocket that had launched the SPOT 1 satellite. This was the first verified case of an accidental collision between two artificial objects in space; however control was eventually regained.

Also not mission ending: between 22nd and 24th May 2022, a large meteoroid hit the James Webb Space Telescope resulting in "significant un-correctable change" to segment C3. This was in addition to six deformations detected on the telescopes primary mirror panels that have been attributed to micrometeoroid strikes.


Not sure:

In April 1973, the second Soviet space station, Salyut 2 was launched without incident and entered orbit successfully. Shortly after, the third stage of the Proton-K rocket that had launched the station also entered orbit, but a couple of days after that the stage exploded creating a cloud of debris. Several days later the station collided with this debris, subsequent damage leaving it without power and attitude control, and depressurized. By May the space station had deorbited.


I had to look twice to realize the DART in your list wasn't the one that deliberately hit something.

Some years ago I saw a solar panel on display at ESTEC , which had a couple of micrometeorite holes. Not sure if its still there.
